# Книга "по компьютерам"

Tags: пк, книги

Посоветуйте книгу "по компьютерам", чтобы всё было ясно и полностью от А до Я. Я не давно начал изучать низкоуровневые языки и понял, что в компьютерах не разбираюсь ни капельки ))) Поэтому, чем глубже и подробней будет, тем лучше...

Comment: @ХэшКод Почему? Я прошу литературу не по тому как правильно пользоваться мышкой и клавиатурой. А я хочу узнать архитектуру компьютера и по возможности знать там каждую железку. И я так понимаю только системные администраторы смогут мне в этом помочь :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Э. Танненбаум "Архитектура компьютера"

Answer (score 0):

Скотт Мюллер "Модернизация и ремонт ПК"

Answer (score 0):

http://my-shop.ru/shop/books/235217.html Компьютерhttp://my-shop.ru/shop/books/325227.html Самоучитель

Изучайте!